# Does dynamic libraries link other libraries for you?

Tags: dll, dynamic-linking

I noticed how you don't have to link opengl32.lib by yourself when you use libraries such as SFML and I'm really wonder how that could be since I have to link opengl32 in my projects that are using my own multimedia library which is a static library? Is it simply because the SFML library is a dynamic library and opengl32 is linked in the SFML project?
This is not a question about SFML, it's rather a question about all DLLs in general.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, DLLs can reference other DLLs, or statically compile them internally. To inspect external dependencies, Microsoft long ago developed a tool called Dependency Walker, in which you can drag a DLL or executable and see which DLLs it depends on (and thus are automatically loaded). The tool used to be shipped with Visual Studio by default, but you can now [download it from here for free](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). That page kind of explains everything else about it.

Comment: Ok thanks. But does it mean that the user of my multimedia library need the .DLL files on their computer that I compiled internally? I guess freetype is a good example.

Comment: If you dynamically linked it your own DLL will only contain the symbol references, so yes, you'll need to ship the referenced DLL as well or have the user install it separately. Nothing much different there with for example DirectX.

Answer (score 1):

If a dynamic library is using another dynamic library, it will automatically get loaded into the process, yes.

Comment: Shouldn't this make it way easier for developers who are using my multimedia library? I mean, I guess they don't even need the required libraries I had to link when I built the multimedia DLL. For example freetype?

Comment: Yes, it can achieve that. You certainly wouldn't want to have to know the complete list of libraries some library you happen to use needs to fulfil its own dependencies. Of course, if you are making your own multimedia DLL, then hopefully you HIDE what it actually uses and doesn't "let" your client code see what the libraries are that you are using (I mean, you don't want client code to use freetype, right - they just say "I want the text in Courier Bold, size 10" (in some way), and then the client code sends the string to be printed...)

Comment: Exactly. That is what I want to achieve. Is it going to be like that by default when I build the dynamic library via vc++ or gcc? I guess I just have to use the static library version of freetype?

Comment: Your DLL will have to link against any libraries that it directly has dependencies on, yes.